# Clojure string/replace fails in my function

Tags: clojure

I want to replace space characters with plus signs in the search query I send to google.

```
(defn search-google [search-term]
  (clojure.string/replace search-term #" " "+")
    (browse-url 
      (str "http://google.ca/search?q=" search-term)))
```

However my function fails as my search-term retains spaces.

```
(search-google "clojure user input")

URISyntaxException Illegal character in query at index 32:
http://google.ca/search?q=clojure user input  java.net.URI$Parser.fail (:-1)
```

I am new at clojure and suspect I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A new fixed search-term is being created, then the fixed one is ignored and the unchanged one is passed to browse-url:

```
(def browse-url println)                                                                                                                                                  
(defn search-google [search-term]                                                                                                                                         
  (let [fixed-search-term (clojure.string/replace search-term #" " "+")]                                                                                                  
    (browse-url                                                                                                                                                           
     (str "http://google.ca/search?q=" fixed-search-term))))  

user> (search-google "a b c")                                                                                                                                             
http://google.ca/search?q=a+b+c                                                                                                                                           
nil
```

Comment: Thanks Arthur and @andrewdotnich for the explanation about `let`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
(defn search-google [search-term]
  (browse-url 
   (str "http://google.ca/search?q="
        (clojure.string/replace search-term #"\s+" "+"))))
```

Notice that the pattern is a regular expression, and you can use `\s+` to indicate that the string match to be replaced should include one or more spaces.

Also be aware that the replace procedure returns a *new* string, the original string is not modified.

Comment: Sorry, that didn't work. Maybe I have to re-bind `search-term` to it's new value. In python it would be `search_term = search_term.replace(' ','+')`

Comment: @exbctel no need to do that, the string is correctly formed before being passed as a parameter, to see it try this: `(str "http://google.ca/search?q=" (clojure.string/replace "a b c d" #"\s+" "+"))` maybe there are other erroneous characters in the search term?

Comment: Thanks Oscar. Moving the `string/replace` into `browse-url` worked. However I ended up using the `let` re-binding suggested by Arthur and Andrew instead.

Comment: @exbctel you're welcome! remember that `let` is useful, but not required to make the code work - you can pass the value directly, as shown above. Also be aware that the other answers don't take in consideration the case where there are more than one spaces in-between

Answer (score 1):

Replace doesn't modify `search-term` in-place, but rather returns a copy of it, which is being thrown away.

Use `let` to bind this value to a name in the function and call `browse-url` with that instead.